# Does $\phi\circ g$ convex imply $\phi\circ f\circ g$ convex?

Tags: analysis, convex-analysis, examples-counterexamples

Assume that $\phi$ is an increasing function and $g$ is a decreasing function with $\phi\circ g$ convex. If $f$ is an increasing convex function does this imply $\phi\circ f\circ g$ is a convex function?

I came to this from an applied problem where we can use the fact that $f\circ \phi\circ g$ is convex and I'd also like to say something about what happens if we did $f$ and $\phi$ in the opposite order.

Comment: Have you tried applying the definition of convexity and seeing what you get?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Counterexample: 
$$\phi(x)=\begin{cases} x+1,\quad & x\le 0 \\ e^x,\quad &x\ge 0\end{cases}$$
$$g(x)=\begin{cases} \ln(-x),\quad & x\le -1 \\ -x-1,\quad &x\ge -1\end{cases}$$
Observe that $\phi(g(x))=-x$, which is convex.

Let $f(x)=x-1$. Then 
$$f(g(x))=\begin{cases} \ln(-x)-1,\quad & x\le -1 \\ -x-2,\quad &x\ge -1\end{cases}$$
which changes sign at $x=-e$. Consequently, 
$$\phi(f(g(x)))=\begin{cases} 
-x/e,  \quad & x\le -e \\ \ln(-x),  \quad & -e\le x\le -1 \\ 
-x-1, \quad & x\ge -1
\end{cases}$$
Convexity fails on $[-e,-1]$.

Comment: In what sense is $-x$ convex? That is not consistent with [this definition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_function).

Comment: It's a straight-line; there is no convexity.

Comment: "... if the line segment between any two points on the graph of the function lies above the graph". With $-x$, the line segment between any two points on the graph of the function lies _on_ the graph.

Comment: OK; I suppose I had something like "strictly convex" in mind.

Comment: Very interesting! I'm trying to think about what's going on here. I guess it's using the fact that an increasing convex function of a decreasing concave function does not have to be convex or concave. Here $\phi\circ g$ is convex but $f\circ g$ and $(\phi)\circ(f\circ g)$ are not.

Comment: Can you find an example where $\phi$ is strictly increasing, $g$ is strictly decreasing, $\phi\circ g$ and $f$ are strictly convex, and $f$ is strictly increasing, but $\phi\circ f\circ g$ is not weakly convex?

Comment: @dfeuer  Any counterexample can be made strictly convex/concave with a little perturbation. Convexity fails on some  interval (such as $[-e,-1]$) by some definite amount. Adding $\epsilon e^x$ to $\phi$ and $f$ maintains the failure of convexity in composition (if $\epsilon>0$ is small enough) and makes $\phi$ and $f$ strictly convex.  The monotonicity is already strict in all three functions.